# Java replace in string html img tags

Tags: java, android, html

I am parsing a json feed and displaying its content in a android webview. Everything works great. But now i want to hide all img tags in that android webview.

The problem is that the content in the webview is showen dynamically, that means i don't know the img tag parameters. So i need something to replace everything in that string that begins with

```
     <img ...  >
```

and ends with

```
   </img>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because none of these answeres worked for me, i finally decided to use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) to filter and remove all img tags.

using jsop was a little bit complex but it worked!!

**EDIT**
Here is an example java code

```
String content = "<h1>title</h1><img src="http://..."></img>";
if(content != null) {
    Document document = Jsoup.parse(content);
    document.select("img").remove();
    content = document.toString();
}
```

Comment: How do you remove image tags using jsoup

Comment: @TasawerKhan its esay, if you want i can edit the answer with a working example

Comment: I found the solution. But if you can that will be helpful to others.

Comment: Great!. I used document.html()

Answer (score 1):

If you handle the String yourself and you set it to the webview, then suppose your content is in a String called `oldWebViewContent` , and try this :

```
String webViewContentExcludeImage = oldWebViewContent.replaceAll("<img .*?</img>","");
```

Comment: Thanks, but didn't worked. Any other solution maybe?

Comment: try to remove `\n` from your string  : `oldWebViewContent=oldWebViewContent.replaceAll("\\n","");` then use the code in the answer.

Comment: There's always the possibility of having something like `<img src=""/>`, which would not work for this example. In fact, an `img` tag may not even have a `/` at all. Due to the nature of HTML, regex is not usually the best thing to use.

Comment: if that is the case, use two replaceAll calls.  one as stated above and one with ("<img.*/>", "")

Comment: What if it doesn't have a close (`/`) tag at all? (As used on the [W3C site](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp))

Comment: @user184994 then use `/?` the boolean operator in the regex.

Comment: I'm just going to leave [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) here.

Comment: I actually use all the above. `oldWebViewContent.replaceAll("<img .*?</img>", "").replaceAll("<img .*?/>", "").replaceAll("<img .*?>", "");` to replace all possible image tag. Not sure if it is the best solution but at least it works for me. Please note that `.replaceAll("<img .*?>", "");` should come last as there is a possibility that it will remove only part of the html eg `<img src=""http://...">` of `<img src=""http://...">something</img>`